# Datagrid view button column image

Tags: vb.net

I have a button column on my datagrid view.  Please advise how to show an image on that button?  Please advise for both design time and run time.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its the same image on every button then this will likely do:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate> 
   <Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Images/YOUR_IMAGE.jpg" />
        <TextBlock>YOUR TEXT</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
   </Button>
 </DataTemplate> 
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And if you want to bind the image from your datasource you will need to implement an IValueConverter - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902540/how-to-change-the-image-of-wpf-datagrid-row-depending-on-binding-value) thread for more details.