# Change listview image based on binded value

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, listview

My program connects to a mysql database and then stores data into a listview. I want to display the rating of the item in the list to be displayed as a picture not a number. Looking at this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902540/how-to-change-the-image-of-wpf-datagrid-row-depending-on-binding-value), I figured out how to display different images using data triggers, but I need a way to specify a range of numbers. Ex, 0-10 = 0stars.png, 11-50 = 1stars.png, etc....

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
After some thought I believe I would be able to run a function after the listview is loaded that is a for loop that would get the value from every row in the column, decide what number range it's in, then re-bind it to the listview. Would this be efficient?

Comment: Create a converter, and implement the logic in the converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a converter

- Bind the ItemsSource to the list of your numbers
- Write a rating converter to convert numbers to images
- Change the ItemTemplate to display the image

e.g.

- xaml

  ```
  <Window
      Name="ThisWnd"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourConverter's Namespace" <!-- the namespace of your converter. -->
      ...>

      <Window.Resource>
          <local:RatingConverter x:Key="RatingConverter"/>
      </Window.Resources>

      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=ThisWnd}">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Image Source="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource RatingConverter}}">
                  </Image>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>

      </ListView>
  </Window>
  ```
- code behind

  ```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
      public List<int> Items
      {
          get;
          set;
      }
  }

  [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Image))]
  public class RatingConverter : IValueConverter
  {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
          int rate = (int)value;
          string imagePath = "1star.png";
          if (rate > 10)
          {
              imagePath = "2star.png";
          }

          return new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.Relative));
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
  }
  ```